# Remove empty zero length rows in list with R

Tags: r

I have list of dataframes and some are empty, how can I remove these?

```
$`S566X7221`
[1] V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21    V22 V23 V24 V25 V26
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I have tried these, but non of them work

```
x[lapply(x,length)>0] 
Filter(length, x)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're close. But you want `nrow`, not `length` (which is actually the number of columns in a data.frame).

```
x <- list(data.frame(A=numeric(),B=numeric()), data.frame(A=1:3, B=4:6), data.frame(A=1,B=2))
x[sapply(x, nrow)>0]
```

Before:

```
> x
[[1]]
[1] A B
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[2]]
  A B
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[3]]
  A B
1 1 2
```

After:

```
> x[sapply(x, nrow)>0]
[[1]]
  A B
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[2]]
  A B
1 1 2
```