# How can I use lapply to remove empty rows from a List of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames.  There are 28 data frames in my list.  Some of the data frames have empty rows but not all.  How can I use `lapply` or a similar function to remove empty rows from all data frames in the list?

Here is what I have tried which I modified from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781198/remove-empty-zero-length-rows-in-list-with-r).  Unfortunately, this returned only those rows that were empty.

```
#Get list of all files that will be analyzed
filenames = list.files(pattern = ".csv")

#read in all files in filenames
mydata_run1 = lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE, quote = "")

#Remove empty rows
mydata_run1 = lapply(mydata_run1, function(x) sapply(mydata_run1, nrow)>0)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to make [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: If no other data is missing, you could use `complete.cases()`.

Comment: This will work when `NA`s occur only in the empty rows: `mydata_run1 = lapply(mydata_run1, function(x) na.omit(x))`

Comment: @EdwardCarney, this approach  removes rows all rows with even 1 NA value.

Comment: Correct. My comment was intended to indicate that it won't work the way @aminards wants it to when NAs occur in other rows than just the "empty" ones. Perhaps, I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to remove empty rows when appeared across all columns.
If so,

```
# remove row data if only all the columns have NA value. 
lapply(data, function(x){ x[rowSums(is.na(x)) != ncol(x),]})
```

output

---

```
$df1
  A B
1 1 4
3 3 6

$df2
  A  B
1 1 NA
3 3  6
```

data

---

```
data <- list(
            df1 = data.frame(A = c(1,NA,3), B = c(4, NA, 6)),
            df2 = data.frame(A = c(1,NA,3), B = c(NA, NA, 6)))
```